# Same day of the week birthdays

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does my birthday and my husband's birthdays fall on the same day of the week always, his birthday is October $8$, $1971$ and mine is July $9$, $1970$?

Comment: There are $91=7\cdot13$ days between your birthdates.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Remember that September has $30$ days

Comment: Because you were born on the same day of the week as your husband's birthday in 1971, and leap day never alls between the two.

Answer (score 0):

The following dates always fall on the same day of the week every year: the last day of February, 4/4, 6/6, 8/8, 10/10, 12/12, 5/9, 9/5, 7/11, 11/7 (for example, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule)). Additionally, since $365\equiv 1\mod{7}$, that day advances by one each year as long as the new year is not a leap year. So let's do a little calculation: your actual birthday, July 9 1970, was a Thursday. Then in 1971 it would fall on a Friday (since 1971 is not a leap year). Therefore July 11 1971 is a Sunday, so that 10/10/71 is also a Sunday. It follows that your husband's birthday, two days before that, falls on a Friday as well. Thus they always fall on the same day of the week.

Note that the two dates remain in synch because the are both on the same side of the end of February. If one were to precede the end of February and the other follow it, then this analysis would not work, and in fact the relation between the days of the week of your birthdays would depend on whether it was a leap year or not. The above analysis also depends, clearly, on the fact that 1971 was not a leap year.

Comment: thursday, and it only works because febraury 29th wasn't between them otherwise every fourth year they lose or gain a day against each other.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. First of all, 1971 was not a leap year; I made it clear that the day advance was only one day except in that case. Second, if you mean that in 1970 his b-day was a Thursday, fine, except that as I clearly stated, it really doesn't matter which day you choose.

Comment: I meant if we had say  january 15th  and a day later than February 29th, then it would be false because every leap year would push the days apart.

Comment: I added an explanation of what happens in that case. It does self-correct, but in each leap year they would not be on the same day (unless, of course, the first year under consideration was a leap year). It gets complicated. But for the dates given, either method works.